# jQuery Ajax syntax unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I've been trying to get something to work with AJAX/jQuery and Servlets, and I keep getting syntax errorrs and the browser doesn't show where the error lies.

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnTest").click(function(){
            var n = $("#vName").val();
            $.get("TestServlet", (nm:n), function(responseText){
                $("#textArea").text(responseText);
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <input type="text" id="vName" value="" />
    <input type="button" value="Ok" id="btnTest" />
    <div id="textArea"></div>
</body>
```

And then in my servlet I have this ;

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try
    {
        String val = request.getParameter("mn");
        String msg = "Hi User";
        if(val!=null)
        msg = "Hi, " + val;

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"...and the browser doesn't show where the error lies."* Any half-decent browser will not only tell you where the error is, but give you a *link* to the line causing the error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(nm:n)` in your call to `$.get` is invalid syntax. You probably meant `{nm:n}`:

```
$.get("TestServlet", {nm:n}, function(responseText){
// Here -------------^----^
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

```
$.get("TestServlet",{ nm:n }, function(responseText)
```